# How do I give give parameters to program run in shellscript?

Tags: bash

For example I have this shellscript:

```
clear
echo "Script is starting now please give input:"
read parameter


cd /path to program
./program $parameter
```

How could I give parameters to the program i am trying to run?

Comment: What you have done is correct (except I would use some quoting of variables). What errors are you facing? & what input are you giving to the `read` step?

Comment: Are you getting a "permission denied error"?

Comment: If you are than change permissions with **chmod 777 /path/program.sh** (777 = full permission to User, Groups and Others). As @anishsane mentioned, use quotes to maintain formatting

Comment: ^^ `777` is almost never a good value for permission, except for shared directories & files. Most likely it should be `755` (if script) or maybe `555` (if binary).

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between a user input and and argument passed. The argument is passed when you run the script, the user input is what you read from terminal while running the script.

**program.sh**

```
clear
echo "Script is starting now please give input:"

# Parameter you passed:
echo "$1 is the parameter you passed."

# capture user input
read parameter

# do what you wish with parameter:
echo "$parameter is the user input read."
```

Make sure you change the permissions for your script.

```
$: chmod u+x /path/to/program.sh
```

Run the script with:

```
./path/to/program.sh argument
```